# Email validation pattern Unclosed Character Class

Tags: java, regex, validation, email

I am using an email validation pattern I found at [How to validate an email](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/) and it works fine except it allows a `+` in the first part of the email and that isn't allowed in my specs.  The original code is

```
public static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

protected boolean isInvalidEmail(String email) {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return !matcher.matches();
}
```

I thought I could just remove the `+` from `"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]` but I get a `Pattern Syntax Exception: Unclosed Character Class`.  Can someone tell me why removing the `+` uncloses the class?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `\\+` portion.

`\\` escapes the `\` character. `\+` escapes the `+` regex operator. Thus `\\+` breaks down to `\+` which means match the literal `+` character.

**Note:** The `+` regex operator means match one or more of the preceding element.

Comment: It's odd though, that they put the `\\+` after the final `-`, isn't it? The `-` only has its literal representation when at the beginning or end of a character class, and otherwise acts as a range operator. So the source of this regex seems untrustworthy.

Comment: @AndrewCheong I thought that was odd as well, but the [top 5 regex testers](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=java+regex+tester&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) don't show any errors and it matches valid strings, like `example-@email.com`. Although, if the hyphen isn't at the beginning or end then it should be escaped (`\-`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it gives you `Unclosed Character Class` is because only removing the `+` now escapes the closing square bracket so it is considered part of the pattern. Hence, the class does not have a matching closing square bracket. As Jonny Henly mentions the solution is to remove the `\\+` to align with your spec, but this gives the answer as to why it is unclosed.

Comment: *this gives the answer as to why it is unclosed* - +1